# Store GAP REPL representation of expression in string

Tags: gap

I have noticed that the representation that is displayed by the GAP REPL (read-evaluate-print loop) when an expression is evaluated sometimes differs from the result of printing that same expression, e.g.:

```
gap> x:=PartialPerm([1,2],[3,4]);
[1,3][2,4]
gap> Print(x);
PartialPerm( [1, 2], [3, 4] );
```

Is there some general way to obtain the former string representation outside of an interactive GAP session which will work for any expression? (Or, failing that, a way that works in the special case of partial permutations?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAP has operations `DisplayString`, `ViewSrting` and `PrintString` documented [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap27.html#X7E72717A82A309F5). Usually, *displaying* an object produces a human-readable relatively complete and verbose output, *viewing* produces a short and concise output, and *printing* produces an output in a complete form which is GAP readable (if at all possible), such that reading the output into GAP produces an object which is equal to the original one.

Depending on the type of the object, they may delegate to each other in the order specified [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X8074A8387C9DB9A8).

In the example in question, we have

```
gap> PrintString(x);
"PartialPerm( \>[ 1, 2 ], \<\>[ 3, 4 ]\<\> )\<"
gap> ViewString(x);
"\>[\>1\<,\>3\<\<]\>[\>2\<,\>4\<\<]"
gap> DisplayString(x);
"<object>\n"
```

As you see, the output have additional control characters `\<` (ASCII 1) and `\>` (ASCII 2) that allow proper line breaks. The function `StripLineBreakCharacters` (see [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap27.html#X86AACCE987F74FA5)) may be used to remove them:

```
gap> StripLineBreakCharacters(PrintString(x));
"PartialPerm( [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] )"
gap> StripLineBreakCharacters(ViewString(x));
"[1,3][2,4]"
gap> StripLineBreakCharacters(DisplayString(x));
"<object>\n"
```

There is also `String` (see [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap27.html#X81FB5BE27903EC32)) which should approximate as closely as possible the character sequence you see if you print an  object:

```
gap> String(x);
"PartialPerm( [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] )"
```

Perhaps for partial permutations that's the best option.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful (although it feels like this shouldn't be this complicated but I guess that's on GAP).

Comment: There is also `String` - will update the answer now.